# Creating new string lists from a Dictionary of lists ( i.e from a dictionary which has string Lists as values)

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary, key-value

I have a dictionary string (key) and value string list.  I would like to, be able to print out  // contents of a list (instead of getting  System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] ), but also  // be able to take each value ( a list of strings) and create new list

Basically I should have 3 lists in the results dictionary ( one consisting of unreal, another //containing // batter and patter and another with 4 words not containing any a's)

I have something like this

```
using System;
    
using System.Collections.Generic;
    
using System.Text;
    
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> wordList = new List<string>() { "unreal", "batter", "butter", "patter", 
                          "tested", "nested", "pested" };
    char letter = 'a';
    
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> results = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    // So at each key ( so the ----a- for instance) it will have it's own dictionary
    foreach (string word in wordList)
    {
         StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
         //   builder.Append(word);
         for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
         {
             //  builder = null;
             if (word[i] == letter)
             {
                 builder.Append(letter);
                 //  key = String.Join(word, wordList);
                 // builder[i] = letter;
             }
             else
             {
                 // builder[i] = '-';
                 builder.Append('-');
             }
         }

         string key = builder.ToString();

         // var result = string.Join(key, word);
         if (results.ContainsKey(key))
         {
             List<string> list = results[key];
             list.Add(word);
         }
         else
         {
             List<string> list = new List<string>();
             list.Add(word);
             results.Add(key, list);
         }
              
         //   results.Add(result)          
    }

    foreach(KeyValuePair<string,List<string>> kvp in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} has {1} words", kvp.Key, kvp.Value.Count);
        // Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use C# types instead of describing in English. Were you trying to say `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`? What does `//` mean? What does "print out contents" instead of getting `List<string>` mean? What are all the comments for?

Answer (score 0):

A more concise way to create the dictionary would be to use `GroupBy` on the list  to group the items by the string representation of the word where all characters are replaced with a `'-'` except for those that equal `letter` (which we create by using the `Select` method to select a `'-'` or the `'a'` character, and then combine the resulting set into a string using `string.Concat`), and then convert that do a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` using `ToDictionary()`, using the `Group.Key` for the dictionary `Key`, and using `ToList()` on the group itself to create the dictionary `Value`:

```
List<string> wordList = new List<string>()
{"unreal", "batter", "butter", "patter", "tested", "nested", "pested"};

char letter = 'a';

Dictionary<string, List<string>> results = wordList
    .GroupBy(item => string.Concat(item.Select(c => c == letter ? c : '-')))
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList());
```

Then you can output the actual item values for each list using `string.Join`:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> kvp in results)
{
    Console.Write("{0} has {1} words: ", kvp.Key, kvp.Value.Count);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", kvp.Value));
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: That is really awesome, Thank you!  I am just wondering how do I go about getting one of the lists ( i.e the batter and patter words) and transfer just those two words into the original wordList list? Is there some way of doing that in the foreach or would it have to be outside?

Comment: `AddRange`to add one list to another: `wordList.AddRange(results["-a----"]);`, but since those words are already in the list, they will now be in there twice. I think I may be misunderstanding your question...is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant!  Thank you.    By the way, I just wondered if it is possible to do another query that would enable me to be able to identify the most frequently occurring char in  wordList?  ( expected output would be  e or t, but ideally e, since that appears in all of the words  whereas t does not!).  How would I go about this?